# Change Stream Duplication if Microservices instance got replicated

Tags: mongodb, reactive-streams, changestream

I have implemented MongoDB Change Stream in a Java Microservice, When i do a replica of my Microservice I See change stream watch is listening twice. Code is duplicated. Any way to stop this?

Comment: Run the application one time?

Comment: check this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007693/mongo-change-streams-running-multiple-times-kind-of-node-app-running-multiple

Answer (score 1):

I gave a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133450/2216134), however as this question is directly related to Java, I feel it is actually more relevant on this question. I assume what you are after is each change being processed only once among many replicated processes.

Doing this with strong guarantees is difficult but not impossible. I wrote about the details of one solution here: https://www.alechenninger.com/2020/05/building-kafka-like-message-queue-with.html

This solution is implemented in a [proof-of-concept library written in Java](https://github.com/alechenninger/roger) that accomplishes this which you are free to use/fork (the blog post explains how it works).

It comes down to a few techniques:

- Each process attempts to obtain a lock
- Each lock (or each change) has an associated [fencing token](http://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html)
- Processing each change must be idempotent
- While processing the change, the token is used to ensure ordered, effectively-once updates.

More details in the [blog post](https://www.alechenninger.com/2020/05/building-kafka-like-message-queue-with.html).