# MongoDB change stream - Duplicate records / Multiple listeners

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, changestream

My question is an extension of the earlier discussion here:
[Mongo Change Streams running multiple times (kind of): Node app running multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007693/mongo-change-streams-running-multiple-times-kind-of-node-app-running-multiple)

In my case, the application is deployed on Kubernetes pods. There will be at least 3 pods and a maximum of 5 pods. The solution mentioned in the above link suggests to use *<this instance's id>* in the $mod operator. Since the application is deployed to K8s pods, pod names are dynamic. How can I achieve a similar solution for my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running stateless workload i am not sure why you want to fix name of POD(deployment).

Fixing PODs names is only possible with [stateful sets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

You should be using statefulset instead of deployment, replication controllers(RC), however, replication controllers are replaced with ReplicaSets.

StatefulSet Pods have a unique identity comprised of an ordinal. For any StatefulSet with N replicas, each Pod in the StatefulSet will be assigned an integer ordinal, from 0 up through N-1, which will be unique across Set.

Comment: I'm okay with any other unique information. I just gave an example of a pod name to compare with the option mentioned in the referenced link. I'm just trying to use the referenced solution for my scenario.

Comment: if you will use stateful sets pod names will not be dynamic.

Comment: That sounds great but unfortunately, I can not use stateful.